# Grouping multiple ingresses into single load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am having multiple ingresses in different namespaces. Now wanted to serve them under a single load balancer in AWS.

I am trying to add below group annotations but they still create different ALBs. Can someone tell me what is missing?

annotations: taken from here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/main/docs/guide/ingress/annotations.md

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: group-alb-test
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '2'
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=dev,Team=test
```

ingress.yml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kp
  name: test-group
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: kp
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '1'    
spec:
  rules:
  - http:    
      paths:
      - path: /ping        
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: kp-wallet-search-service
          servicePort: 80               
---          
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: kp
  name: test-group2
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: kp
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.order: '2'     
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-403: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"403","messageBody":"403 External access to endpoint not allowed"}}
spec:
  rules:
  - http:    
      paths:
      - path: /ping2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: response-403
          servicePort: use-annotation               
---
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes. we need to upgrade alb ingress controller to v2 version. it supports multiple ingress rules in different namespaces

Comment: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.1/deploy/upgrade/migrate_v1_v2/